# app inventor Autosize text size

Tags: app-inventor

I have produced a lovely app for a mobile on app inventor 2 that looks awful on my tablet.  I can set component sizes to percentage and autosize so they fill the screen ok but the font size in the components stay much too small.

I looked back at some stuff I did years ago in app inventor 1 and did not have this problem but cannot see how I managed to make the font size change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use font size method in the Block. you can define the font size according to you auto-size like.
 if my Vertical1 width = size+5  then font = size+5

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Could you please be a bit more specific and reformat you answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the Screen1 properties, you can set sizing to responsive. This might fix your problem.

[image: sizing property]

According to the [App Inventor page](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/responsiveDesign.html) on responsive sizing:

> To accommodate this choice, App Inventor includes a screen property called Screen.Sizing.  Screen.Sizing can be set to either fixed or responsive.   When sizing is fixed, App Inventor creates apps for a screen of size 320 pixels wide and 460 pixels high, but it scales the app’s appearance to match the actual size of the screen that the app is running on. This display is essentially equivalent to how App Inventor apps were rendered on Tablets prior to App Inventor version 145.